# Missing material icons in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

`implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"` is included on my `build.graddle` file with the latest stable realease of Compose (1.1.1).

However, I am unable to reference any of the NetworkWifiXBar icons (e.g. NetworkWifi1Bar ) as seen [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.style=Rounded&icon.set=Material%20Icons&icon.query=network%20wifi).

I had the understanding that all icons were included with `material-icons-extended`.

Is this an issue on my end or are these not included?

Comment: I can see the icons . `import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.NetworkWifi1Bar` works for me. I am using compose version - 1.2.0-alpha07

Comment: @Abhimanyu Changed my compose version to 1.2.0-alpha07 and it works. Haven't tried more versions, but that one fixes the issue. Honestly, I didn't even bother trying a newer compose version because it didn't sound like a logical fix, should have known better.

Comment: Is there a way to know what version is required for an icon? I'm trying to access `icons.sharp.Monitoring` [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.category=Business%26Payments&icon.platform=web&icon.style=Sharp) to no avail, with version 1.2.1

Comment: Using the latest version of material-icons-extended or even the 1.5 alpha, so many icons are missing. So I'm just now manually importing them.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the below [Compose Material dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material) updated on *Feb-22, 2024*:

**Stable Release:**

`implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.6.2"`

**Alpha Release:**

`implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.7.0-alpha03"`

Comment: I still cannot find the Trolley icon not sure why

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre, You can get a trolly icon from `Icons.Filled.ShoppingCart`

Comment: that is not the one I want, the one I need is Icons.Filled.Trolley seen here https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.style=Filled&icon.set=Material+Icons&icon.query=trolley

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre do you have found the icons?

Comment: @RumitPatel is there a `materials3-icons-extended` dependency available or is it still material1?

Comment: @mars8 , Nope, I can't find any separate dependency for `material3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dependency implementation `"androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:x.x.x"` and if after that you still find only this [empty list of icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXq9h.png)
**you just need give more time to Android Studio for indexing icons** - wait more after place dot or start typing some icon name